# Parentheses around multiple values in implied DO loop - "error: expected a right parenthesis in expression"

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

When migrating from GNU FORTRAN Compiler 4.3.2 to 4.8.5 a user got an error

```
p.for:227.25:

      write(3,446) ((r(i),ERC(i),EIC(i),ERp(i),EIp(i)),i=1,I1)
                         1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

Here the output list is built using the implied DO-loop construct. The error persists even when compiling with `--std=legacy`.

The problem is easy to fix. When I remove the parentheses around the list of array elements the code compiles and seems to work as expected.

```
      write(3,446) (r(i),ERC(i),EIC(i),ERp(i),EIp(i),i=1,I1)
```

I would be content with this fix, however our users often store multiple copies of code on different systems and exchange code between them seemingly at random. On the other hand, the makefiles and build scripts are usually specific to our cluster.

It would be nice to find that there is a command line option that will let such code pass syntax checking. I could not find anything like `-ffixed-parenthesized-values-in-implied-loop` in the list of available GNU Fortran Compiler Language Options.

**Q:** Is it possible to tweak a build script to let such statement compile without modifying the source code?

Comment: Why do you want an option to which allows non-standard code instead of changing that code to standard Fortran everywhere? You can't just invent your own syntax and then expect there to be an option to allow it.

Comment: Unless you can find some reference that the code conforms to Fortran 77 or 66, but I am not convinced.

Comment: I suspect that the gfortran developers considered it a bug to have ever supported that syntax.  And not sufficiently (ab)used to be worth adding a compiler flag.  [If a flag were added to allow reversion for each compiler correction, documentation would be very large indeed.]  So, what would you consider an answer to this question?  Obviously a "use -fmagic-option", but a convincing "there isn't, and this is the proof"?

Comment: @VladimirF I find many Fortran programmers are used to non-standard syntax supported by their favourite compilers. As they own the code, not me, it is often easier option to conform with the owner of the code, not make them conform to the standard. Intel compiler for instance is very permissive in this respect. Fortran had a very long history before the standards process caught up.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov I am well aware of the history and I am saying convert the code. Or use a vendor specific syntax and don't be surprised your are locked to use the vendor's compiler. They sometimes used to do extensions exactly to prevent people from using competitor's compiler.

Comment: Or just raise a request on bugzilla to support that with `--std=legacy`. If you create a patch the gfortran developers could use, it could be perhaps accepted. `STRUCUTRE` and `UNION` extensions were accepted from patches supplied by users.

Comment: @francescalus My humble intention is to make this post useful for future reference. I would definitely accept a link to a bug tracker or mailing list post where this bug is discussed, or an explanation that this is an instance of some more general situation... Or something completely different, since our users' build scripts do not look sophisticated at all.